# Link library with common symbols in kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I have a somewhat unusual situation, where I am trying to port a Linux kernel module that was designed for 2.4.9 to the latest kernel. The module consists of two parts, an open source wrapper, and a closed source precompiled library.

I managed to solve most of the problems with the wrapper and got it compile against 4.7.1, but I got this error when I tried to load it: `please compile with -fno-common`

This appears to be because the closed source library was not compiled with the option. At some point, `-fno-common` was added to the kernel build options and eventually support for common symbols was [removed from the module loading code](https://lwn.net/Articles/19108/).

Is there any way I can get this module to load?